# Do I need to inform anyone that I plan to stay on after my week's holiday to America?

Tags: usa, esta

I booked a week's holiday to America to see my boyfriend, but we have since decided that if my visit goes well we would like me to miss my flight home and stay for a couple of months. (Ensuring to return to my home country within the 90 day ESTA limit).

As long as I return within the 90-day limit allowed, will I encounter any problems doing it this way?

Do I need to inform anyone that my stay will be longer than originally planned?

Comment: As long as you have a valid ESTA, which means you are traveling from a VWP approved country (and have the correct type of passport), you'll be granted up to 90 days to visit. Have fun and hope all goes well with you. (I don't have time at the moment to do a fully-fledged answer showing links and sources, so this will have to do, for me.)

Comment: Pnuts, what I meant was they will see my return flight for a weeks time, and if I decide not to catch it, I was curious as to whether I needed to let them know why.

Comment: You need to inform the airline, to change your ticket!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a stamp like this (provided by Photographers Direct):

[image]

Which has a date by which you have to leave the country and it's within 1 week of the date of your entry, you are allowed to remain in the country for the full 90 days that are permitted for you by the US Visa Waiver Program.  So if you're planning to leave within 90 days it should not be an issue without having to notify anyone.

Comment: I don't understand your "within 1 week of the date of your entry" comment. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @greghewgill The comment is simple: OP had mentioned that she was plannin 1 week stay, which turned into 2 months, etc. So upon entry to the US she potentially could receive a stamp like I linked where she is allowed to remain in the country until date mentioned even though technically she could be allowed to stay for 90 days under VWP

Comment: I would think the stamp in the passport takes precedence over any 90 day default rule from the VWP. If I got a stamp in my passport that states I am admitted until some particular date, I would make certain that I either (a) leave by that date, or (b) request an extension of stay. After all, the immigration officer who stamped the passport has final say on the conditions of admission.

Comment: @GregHewgill That's correct which is exactly what the answer says you're reading before and after the picture as 2 separate sentences.  They are not (capitalization notwithstanding)